# Backbone.js View on TodoMVC: function and it's argument and how does it works

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, underscore.js, todomvc

I am studying Backbone.js through the example todomvc application from here: 
http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/

And I'm sort of stuck in the app-view.js part here: 
https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app-view.js

Here's the snippet of the code:

```
    // Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
    // appending its element to the `<ul>`.
    addOne: function (todo) {
        var view = new app.TodoView({ model: todo });
        this.$list.append(view.render().el);
    },
```

Where did the 'todo' variable comes from on the function 'addOne'? 
I searched the whole project files and so far didn't find any specific function that specifies or initialize the 'todo' variable. 
I tried to read the Backbone.js and Underscore.js docs on their website and so far haven't find the explanation.

Comment: from `initialize: function() {... this.listenTo(app.todos, 'add', this.addOne); ...}` app-view.js line 27 , also `'keypress #new-todo': 'createOnEnter'` triggers `createOnEnter` which creates model in collection `app.todos.create(this.newAttributes())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to make what @Evgeniy said more readable..

When you listen to 'add' on a collection the first thing that is passed to the listening method is the added model:

```
this.listenTo(app.todos, 'add', this.addOne);
```

Here is the line in the backbone source:

```
(model = toAdd[i]).trigger('add', model, this, options);
```

So you can see the first param is the added model, then the collection, then any options passed through from `this.collection.add(model, [options])`.

`addAll` is also calling `addOne` - it loops over all the models and adds views for them one-by-one:

```
app.todos.each(this.addOne, this);
```

In each case the first param is going to be a model which needs a view added for it.

Comment: @Evgeniy So, you're saying that this function:
'this.listenTo(app.todos, 'add', this.addOne);'
Automatically pass argument into 'addOne' function, and the argument is the model name of the collection. Is that correct?

Comment: @AnzhariPurnomo Yes - it automatically passes the model that was just added to the collection

Comment: Can you help explain to me step by step on the source code? And preferrably the basic concept on how is this possible, so the next time I stumbled into something similar maybe I could try to understand by myself. :D